# Trouble with Cron sending email after python script execution

Tags: python, cron

I have a python script I'm successfully executing every night at midnight. It's outputting the log file, however, I want it to also send an email with the log contents.

I've read this is pretty use to do, but I've had no luck thus far. I've tried this but it does not work. Does anyone else have some other suggestions?

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04, if that makes a difference with the mail smtp.

```
MAILTO=mcgoga12@wfu.edu

0 0 * * * /usr/bin/python /home/grant/Developer/Projects/StudyBug/Main.py > /home/grant/Desktop/Studybuglog.log 2>&1
```

Answer (score 1):

Cron will send everything sent by the command to its standard output (what would be sent to the screen if you ran the command from the command line) in an email to the email address in MAILTO.

Unfortunately for you, you are changing the behaviour of this command using shell redirection.  If you ran the command exactly as written above, there would be nothing shown on the screen because everything is written to the file (because you redirect standard output to the file using the '>' operator).

If you want an email, remove the >, and everything after it and then test.

If you also want to write to a log file, you might try the 'tee' command, or changing your script to take a log file as a command line argument, and write to both the log file and the standard output.

Comment: Unfortunately, removing the > and everything after it did not work. Still not receiving any emails from cron.

Comment: Do you have sendmail, postfix, or some other mailer running on the system?  If so, does it function?